# how can i increase the height of an inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, autoresizingmask, inputaccessoryview

I have spent several days on this with no solution in sight.

I have an `inputAccessoryView` which consists of a `UIView` containing a `textView` and two buttons. The behaviour of the `inputAccessoryView` is as expected and works fine in all cases except one.

When the height of the textView increases, I am trying to increase the height of the `inputAccessoryView` by the same amount.  When I redefine the height of the `inputAccessoryView` in `textViewDidChange`, the `inputAccessoryView` increases height downwards over the keyboard instead of upwards.

I have tried many different suggestions from SO but nothing has worked.  I guess it is the automatically added `NSLayoutConstraint` of the `inputAccessoryView` but I have no idea how to change that value in swift and iOS 8.3.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    var contentSize = messageTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(messageTextView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max))

    inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height = contentSize.height + 16

}
```

adding

```
inputAccessoryView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

to the above code helps and the inputAccessoryView height increases upwards correctly however I get Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints for several constraints and it is very difficult to identify the offenders.  Also I get an odd effect of the textView creating extra space below on every second instance of a new line.

thanks.

Comment: i've noticed the first call of textViewDidChange does correctly resize the inputAccessoryView without the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints line,  but subsequent calls do not have any effect.  I wonder why that is and how i can restore it to that initial state everytime

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To make input accessory view grow vertically you just set its `autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight`, calculate its `intrinsicContentSize` and let the framework do the rest.

The code:

```
class InputAccessoryView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {

    let textView = UITextView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // This is required to make the view grow vertically
        self.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight

        // Setup textView as needed
        self.addSubview(self.textView)
        self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[textView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["textView": self.textView]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[textView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["textView": self.textView]))

        self.textView.delegate = self

        // Disabling textView scrolling prevents some undesired effects,
        // like incorrect contentOffset when adding new line,
        // and makes the textView behave similar to Apple's Messages app
        self.textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        // Calculate intrinsicContentSize that will fit all the text
        let textSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.textView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: textSize.height)
    }

    // MARK: UITextViewDelegate

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // Re-calculate intrinsicContentSize when text changes
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very concise answer.

Comment: How did you know how to do this? It's like magic how it just works! I'd love to know the process you went through to learn this technique.

Comment: in iOS 11, this method only works when the text entered causes the `UITextBox` to grow. When shrinking, it stays the same size.

Comment: Just in case anyone is new here, it's `override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { ... }` and `autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight` in the current swift version (4.2). 
Great answer BTW

Answer (score 4):

Fast forward to 2020, you can just do the following, everything else the same as in maxkonovalov's answer

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return .zero
}

// MARK: UITextViewDelegate

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    sizeToFit()
}
```