# UILabel in inputAccessoryView temporarily invisible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, inputaccessoryview

I put a `UILabel` in an `inputAccessoryView` as a kind of placeholder for text view. When my app is built and run, and the view controller is pushed on the navigation stack for the first time, everything works fine. However, for all subsequent pushes, the `UILabel` is invisible until the view controller is fully presented.

[image] Note the "Leave a comment" at the bottom

I also found that if I don't call `setNavigationBarHidden`, the problem goes away. Below is part of the code. `ExpandableIAView` is just a custom `UIView` with placeholder `UILabel` added using auto layout.

```
class DetailedPageController: UICollectionViewController {

    lazy var inputContainerView: ExpandableIAView = {
        let view = ExpandableIAView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        view.delegate = self
        return view
    }()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            return inputContainerView
        }
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**ExpandableIAView**

Copied directly from here ([how can i increase the height of an inputAccessoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822504/how-can-i-increase-the-height-of-an-inputaccessoryview)). The placeholder `UILabel` is constrained to the top, left, and bottom anchors of the view.

Comment: Show code of ExpandableIAView

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use just `UILabel` as `inputAccessoryView` it does the same. -> https://gist.github.com/olejnjak/e29fa5f5647aaa6d74bb754751cdb878